# Need a function that has type 'a * 'b -> 'b -> 'a

Tags: function, ocaml

I'm new to OCAML, I'm trying this :

```
fun(a,b) b -> a;;
```

but I get this instead:

```
'a * 'b -> 'c -> 'a
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You will just need to annotate the type of the value explicitly. The compiler won't know otherwise that you meant `'b` and `'c` to be the same. (Notice it might be easier to understand if you name your parameters differently, like `fun(x,y) y -> x` or even better `fun(x,y) z -> x` - these are all equivalent and have the type `'a * 'b -> 'c -> 'a`).

Comment: Generally this kind of question is a homework assignment that makes an interesting puzzle. There are ways to get the desired type to be inferred other than by ascribing types to the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

First, your function has the strange property that the second parameter (named `b`) is going to shadow the second element of the first parameter (a tuple). In other words, in the body of your function the name `b` refers only to the second parameter and the second element of the tuple can't be accessed.

You would get the same type if you defined your function like this:

```
# fun (x, y) z -> x;;
- : 'a * 'b -> 'c -> 'a = <fun>
```

It's important to realize that the names of the parameters are completely unrelated to the names used for the type variables.

You can give your function the desired type if you make sure the second parameter is of the same type as the second element of the tuple. The purpose of the exercise is to get you to think about the type inference mechanism enough to think of a way to get this to happen. What operation could the function perform that can only be done on two values of the same type (but for any type)?

Comment: "*What operation could the function perform*" - nothing useful though, right? Its result would always be ignored.

Comment: Right, it's just a puzzle not a realistic programming assignment. But it teaches about type inference (or this is what I think anyway).

Comment: In the Reason Discord, i had given this advice: 'i have one tip for you, use parameter names that match the generic type names as closely as possible. i find it makes them easier to think about. so, `fun (a, b1) b2 -> ...`'

Comment: If it helps keep things clearer, go for it. It's not unheard of to use a variable name that's the same as its type (e.g., `let rec length list = ...`).

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You just have to impose some kind of constraint to force the two arguments to have the same type. It has to be something very polymorphic. *If you use the Core library this will require some more work.*

The following works, but the warnings are a bit messy. The warnings exist specifically to ask us why we're making a useless comparison.

```
# fun (a1, b1) b2 -> b1 = b2; a1;;
Line 1, characters 19-26:
Warning 10 [non-unit-statement]: this expression should have type unit.
Line 1, characters 19-26:
Warning 10 [non-unit-statement]: this expression should have type unit.
- : 'a * 'b -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
```

We can get around that either by locally binding to `_` or using `ignore`.

```
# fun (a1, b1) b2 -> ignore (b1 = b2); a1;;
- : 'a * 'b -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
# fun (a1, b1) b2 -> let _ = b1 = b2 in a1;;
- : 'a * 'b -> 'b -> 'a = <fun>
```